# Wordpress -> Display ONLY second level categories

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I want to exclude top level and 3+ level post categories when viewing a single post. Getting rid of top level is no problem but not sure how i'd go about removing 3+ level. Can anyone shed light on how to deal with this?

This is what I have now:

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );
// now you can view your category in array:
// using var_dump( $categories );
// or you can take all with foreach:
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    var_dump($category);
    if($category->parent) echo $category->term_id . ', ' . $category->slug . ', ' . $category->name . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the second level, you'll want to run two loops - one to identify the id's of the top-level, so that you can then identify the categories that have a parent ID that is in the top-level (which means it's a second level).

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );

// Set up our array to store our top level ID's
$top_level_ids = [];
// Loop for the sole purpose of figuring out the top_level_ids
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    if( ! $category->parent ) {
        $top_level_ids[] = $category->term_id;
    }
}

// Now we can loop again, and ONLY output terms who's parent are in the top-level id's (aka, second-level categories)
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    // Only output if the parent_id is a TOP level id
    if( in_array( $category->parent_id, $top_level_ids )) {
        echo $category->term_id . ', ' . $category->slug . ', ' . $category->name . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Tracking top level IDs and using that data to eval... good idea. Thanks for the insight!